# spring boot .env variables in application.properties

Tags: spring-boot, maven, environment-variables, pom.xml, application.properties

I have created .env file where I keep variables now I want them to be defined in my application.properties but this is not working. What do I need to add to get the variables.

**.env file**

```
MYSQLDB_USER=root
MYSQLDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.profiles.active = dev
```

**application-dev.properties**

```
# mysql database properties
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb?useUnicode=true&serverTimezone=UTC&server&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username = ${MYSQLDB_USER}
spring.datasource.password = ${MYSQLDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
        
# hibernate properties
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
```

Comment: what error do you see?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This won't happen automatically. You can make it work by adding this to your `application-dev.properties`:

```
spring.config.import=optional:file:.env[.properties]
```

Another option is to use an additional library that adds support for this, such as https://github.com/paulschwarz/spring-dotenv.

There is [some discussion](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/24229) about adding support for this in Spring Boot, but it is not a high priority.

Comment: Where does the `.env` file have to be placed? What is `[.properties]` doing?

Comment: With this example, `.env` is in the current working directory when the application is run. You can add a path to the file if necessary. `[.properties]` is telling Spring Boot to treat the file as a Java properties file (as opposed to a YAML file). Without the file extension, Spring Boot doesn't know the format without this hint.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Current working directory as in the root of the project (same level as pom.xml) or in resources (same level as application.properties)?

Comment: Answering my own question in case it helps anyone - this video explains everything https://youtu.be/PmGLn3ua_lU?t=686