# How .env file is read by docker-compose & application.properties in Spring Boot app?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I deploy my Spring Boot app and when I set some variables on .env, docker-compose and application.yml, I am confused. So, could you please clarify me about the following points?

Assume that I have the following files:

***.env:***

```
DB_NAME=employee_db
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=pass
JWT_SECRET=mySecretKey
```

***docker-compose:***

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  db:
    container_name: employee-db
    image: postgres:14.6-alpine
    env_file: ./.env
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_NAME}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
```

***applicatipn.yml:***

```
spring:
  ... code omitted for brevity
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/${DB_NAME}
    username: ${DB_USERNAME}
    password: ${DB_PASSWORD}

app:
  security:
    jwtSecret: ${JWT_SECRET}
```

After reading the related documentation;

**1.** As far as I know, `.env` file is read by `docker-compose` files and the database is created by using the credentials in the `.env` file. Right?

**2.** On the other hand, `application.yml` file is used when application is running. If we do not pass environment variables while running the app, these values e.g. `DB_USERNAME` is read from the `.env` file, is that true?

Just want to be clarified by a simple scenario after reading the related documentation.

Answer (score 2):

[Spring reads properties from many places](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config) but it does not read a `.env` file.  It would read an `application.properties` or `application.yml` [in the current directory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.files); the Java properties file syntax will be slightly different from the `.env` syntax.  Based on what you've shown I'd expect your Spring application to have some startup trouble resolving the `spring.datasource.url` and other configuration properties.

For Spring, one of those options is to set properties from environment variables, with [specific rules on how the names are mapped](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.relaxed-binding.environment-variables).  In a Spring context I'd tend to use the environment variable names that match what Spring expects; for example

```bash
export SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/employee_db
export SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=postgres
export SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=pass
./gradlew bootRun
```

You do not need to set placeholder values in the `application.yml` bundled into your jar file.

---

In a Compose context, one tricky thing is that there are two different layers of environment variables.  Compose reads the ordinary shell environment and [merges in the `.env` file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/envvars-precedence/), and these values are applied when [resolving variable references in the Compose file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#variable-substitution).  Each container has its own separate environment, which is specified by per-container [`environment:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#environment) and [`env_file:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#env_file) settings.  A value is not passed from the host into a container unless you've set one of these.

Let's say you're running both parts in Compose, with the `.env` file you show.  Those specific variable names aren't meaningful to either Compose or Spring, so you don't need to include a `env_file: .env` line.  But you can use those variables in defining the names they do understand.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:14.6-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_NAME}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
    # as you have it, but no `env_file:` (or `container_name:`)
  app:
    build: .
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/${DB_NAME}
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: ${DB_USERNAME}
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
```

Comment: Hi David, thanks a lot for these wonderful explanations, voted up. Actually, this issue is really very confused for me and probably for many other developers. From your explanations, I am clarified, but also need to clarify some points. Could you helps me for these issues and reply one by one? >>>

Comment: **1.** As far as I see, I can use `environment` section instead of using an `.env` file. However, when I use it in `docker-compose` or `application.yml` then I cannot manage these environment variables at a single point. Because, my `docker-compose` and `application.yml` files are read this `.env` file (when docker-compose and running app via command). Am I wrong?

Comment: **2.** I am also wondering the effect of the profile to these files. AS far as I remember, the default ones are always executed and the profile specific files overrides to the default one when the related profile is active. For example, when active profile is dev, then `application.yml` is executed and `application-dev.yml` overrides it. Is that true? If so, is it valid for `.env` - `.env-dev` ?

Comment: **3.** What about keeping sensitive data in a Spring Boot app that deployed to a Docker container? I have made lots of search and could not find any proper approach. Some of them is useful, but not applicable to Docker. Any idea?

Comment: Comments aren't a really great place to try to answer multiple additional questions.  The specific thing I'll call out here is that environment variables do override the `src/main/resources/application.yml` file, and these settings that are very very specific to this Compose setup are probably easier to specify and change in Compose environment variables rather than trying to set up a Spring profile, compiled into your jar file, that happens to match this particular Compose file.

Comment: SOrry, but I could not understand anything from your last comment. Could you please try to reply my questions instead of explaining different perspectives?

Comment: Spring Boot won't consider a `.env` file automatically, but you can explicitly import the values from that file into your `application.yml`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73055072/1299533

Comment: @ScottFrederick Thanks a lot Scott. As far as I see, docker-compose and application.yml/prop files are read .env file if the environment variables are not provided via commad. Right?

Answer (score 1):

`docker-compose` reads `.env` and use it in `environment` section as in your docker-compose example.
If you need use it in app container with `applicatipn.yml` or in another place inside container, you should use `environment` as for database to pass variables into container, as example

```
environment:
  DB_USERNAME: ${DB_USERNAME}
```

or mounting `.env` file into container and read it by you app.

Comment: Do you mean that in order to read environment variables by application.properties in the container, I can add `environment` section to the `application.yml` file or copy the `.env` file to the container as the other project files?

Comment: Another issue is that, I also seen `$DB_USERNAME` notation besides `${DB_USERNAME}`. Which one should I use with the docker-compose file v >= 3.8 ?

Comment: to read variables inside container you should add these variable by `environment` in compose or use -r key in `docker run` command. As `application.yml`, you app read this file and sees there variables and trying change it by value from environment or from .env file(if your set it in your app, to read variable fron this file) but you shoult mount this file to container by `volume`, not COPY in `Dockerfile`

Comment: format `environment` is DB_USERNAME: ${DB_USERNAME:-default_value_here_if_need}

Comment: Thanks a lot, voted up. the only thing that I don't understand is how to mount `.env` file to container by volume. Is it a common approach and could you please give an example? Because, it may be useful for me to keep my sensitive data if it is suitable.

Comment: @hear [read this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volumes) docs. You need volume type bind to mount file or directory into container. Short syntax is like this `./.env:/app/.env`