How to properly access environment variables in application.yml from projects root directory in a Spring Boot application?
I'm trying to setup Postgres for a service in Spring Boot 3 but I can't get the environment variables to work.
Hardcoding the DB properties work just fine as shown below.
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/abc-shop
    username: postgres
    password: postgres

But using the following gives the error.
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://${POSTGRES_HOST}:${POSTGRES_PORT}/${POSTGRES_DB}
    username: ${POSTGRES_USER}
    password: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}

java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver org.postgresql.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:postgresql://${POSTGRES_HOST}:${POSTGRES_PORT}/${POSTGRES_DB}

I have the environment variables in a .env file in the project's root dir and I'm also passing them
from the docker-compose file.
Here is the .env file -
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
POSTGRES_DB=abc-shop
POSTGRES_HOST=localhost
POSTGRES_PORT=5432

Here is the docker-compose -
version: '3.8'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgress_db
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_HOST: ${POSTGRES_HOST}
      POSTGRES_PORT: ${POSTGRES_PORT}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  postgres_data:

I've checked inside the postgres container in the local machine and the environment variables are present there. Spring just can't seem to read them. Additionally, on a prior project, I got it to work just like this in a production environment where I had the environment variables in GitHub Actions secrets.
Also It's obvious that hardcoding the values in a development environment doesn't really matter and I'm aware of that, I'm just wondering why this won't work.
Let me know if you need more info, Thanks!

You don't have a Spring boot service in that docker compose. Do I assume correctly that you have the spring boot application running locally on your host? If so, how do you pass the variable of the env file to it?

Might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73053852/spring-boot-env-variables-in-application-properties

There seems to be some discrepancy between your definitions and your usage. The compose.yaml you've posted starts the PostgreSQL container -- with the correct(!) variables. You've said as much yourself by stating that "hardcoding the values" in your Spring application works.
However, you have not stated how your application is started. If this is going to work, you need to pass the same variables to the JVM that executes it. To phrase it simply, you've shown that you have made the "receiver" of the host/DB/credentials accept those. Don't forget to also make the "sender" (i.e. your Spring application acting as the client to the PostgreSQL server) "know" the same information! The fact that the exception shows the ${...} parts as uninterpolated seems to indicate that the env vars are missing for the process that executes your Java code.
